# Can Pimcore bundles define new services?

Tags: symfony, bundle, pimcore

Senior Pimcore Certification Program has Part#7 'Extending Pimcore':

Question 4: What are special characteristics unique to Pimcore bundles compared to Symfony bundles?

1. [X] In the extension manager, you're able to trigger installation/uninstallation of bundles.
2. [X] Pimcore bundles add methods to natively register JS and CSS files to be loaded with the admin interface and in editmode.
3. [X] Pimcore bundles show up in the extension manager and can be enabled/disabled from there.
4. [ ] Pimcore bundles cannot be installed via composer.
5. [ ] **Pimcore bundles can define new services, routes and can hook into the event
   system.**

The item #5 is accepted only unchecked.
But why is it correct that services cannot be defined, and the event system hooked?

I personally created many services and Event Listeners inside custom bundles -- works...

Answer (score 1):

The question asks "What are special characteristics *unique to Pimcore bundles compared to Symfony bundles*?

Regular Symfony bundles allow for you to define new services, routes and can hook into the event system.

Therefore it is not unique to pimcore bundles.